# How to merge lists with common elements in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, merge

I'm trying to merge all lists in a list of lists that have common elements. I have some working code. However, it seems to break on this example:

```
def merge_subs(lst_of_lsts):
    res = []
    for row in lst_of_lsts:
        for i, resrow in enumerate(res):
            if row[0]==resrow[0]:
                res[i] += row[1:]
                break
            else:
                res.append(sorted(row))
    return sorted(res)
```

The input is:

```
merge_subs([[1, 7, 3], [1, 7, 5], [2, 0, 4], [2, 0, 6], [3, 7, 1], [3, 7, 5], [4, 0, 2], [4, 0, 6], [5, 7, 1], [5, 7, 3], [6, 0, 2], [6, 0, 4]])
```

My result is:

```
[[0, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 7]]
```

but I should be getting:

```
[[0, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the condition of merge? Your code's intention is to check only the first element of each list.

Comment: You result is not the output I get from running that. It does seem like graph connected components.

Comment: I don't think your result is what you'll get from the code you've written above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use recursion:

```
def group(d, _start, _c = [], _seen = [], _used=[]):
  r = [i for i in d if any(c in _start for c in i) and i not in _seen and i not in _used]
  if not r:
    yield set(_c)
    for i in d:
      if i != _start and i not in _used:
         yield from group(d, i, _c=[], _seen=[], _used=_used+[i, *r])
  else:
    yield from group(d, _start, _c=_c+[i for b in r for i in b], _seen=_seen+r, _used=_used+r)

data = [[1, 7, 3], [1, 7, 5], [2, 0, 4], [2, 0, 6], [3, 7, 1], [3, 7, 5], [4, 0, 2], [4, 0, 6], [5, 7, 1], [5, 7, 3], [6, 0, 2], [6, 0, 4]]
result = list(map(list, {tuple(i) for i in group(data, data[0], _seen=[data[0]]) if i}))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Ajax1234, this problem can be solved using recursion, specifically a tail recursion:

```
def merge(lists, results=None):

    if results is None:
        results = []

    if not lists:
        return results

    merged = set(lists[0])
    output = []
    
    for li in lists[1:]:

        if merged.intersection(li):
            merged = merged.union(li)
        else:
            output.append(li)

    results.append(list(merged))

    return merge(output, results)
```

And the results look like this:

```
>>> merge([[1, 7, 3], [1, 7, 5], [2, 0, 4], [2, 0, 6], [3, 7, 1], [3, 7, 5], [4, 0, 2], [4, 0, 6], [5, 7, 1], [5, 7, 3], [6, 0, 2], [6, 0, 4]])
[[1, 3, 5, 7], [0, 2, 4, 6]]
>>> merge([[2, 3], [3, 4], [2, 1], [2, 5], [6, 7], [1, 8], [9, 3]])
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for
`merge( [[2, 3], [3, 4], [2, 1], [2, 5], [6, 7], [1, 8],  [9, 3]])` which returns `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9], [6, 7], [8, 1]]` instead of `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9], [6, 7]]`

Comment: @PalimPalim yep, you're right :) I've fixed the code, now it works as expected.